# Skew-Symmetric Gain Matrix to Encourage Exploration

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, dynamics

I am reading a [paper on controls](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eschwager/MyPapers/SchwagerICRA08Consensus.pdf) and it has the following snippet:

> We propose to use the control law
>
> $$u_i = K(CV_i − p_i)$$
> , where K is a (potentially time-varying) uniformly positive definite control gain matrix, which may have a skew-symmetric component to encourage other tasks, for example exploration.

**Question:** How does skew symmetric gain matrix encourage exploration, and also exploration of what exactly?

Comment: Suppose your state is $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and the controller $u = Kx$, where $K = [k_1,-f_1;f_1,k_2]$ is the skew-symmetric and positive definite gain matrix. If you think about it, at each time step what is then happening, assuming a linear system, is $\dot{x}_1 \sim k_1 x_1 - f_1 x_2$ and similarly $\dot{x}_2 \sim f_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2$. Therefore from the dynamics the controller is moving the state trajectories into different regions as opposed to the diagonal feedback controller which just moves the state components in their respective directions.

Comment: Well quite nicely explained. But why would we want controller to move the state trajectories to different region then desired?

Comment: That I don’t know. Perhaps depending on the problem it makes sense. If it’s a stabilizing controller, then either way it’ll get you to some point that you want to go. The only difference is *how* it gets there.

Comment: I see. the "how" part makes sense.The system will eventually be stabilized but "how" does it stabilize depends on the skewness of the matrix, right?

Comment: Yea exactly. At least that’s how I’m thinking of it